# Android 2.3 & above: How to draw 2 squares of biggest size in either portrait or landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout

My Android app is for Gingerbread and above. It creates screen output of a graph and a text table. Each is square in shape and drawn using an imageview. These are placed with the layout xml separately within a linear layout. I want the squares the same size and as large as possible. In portrait mode they are stacked and in landscape mode they are side by side. There is nothing else drawn by the app.

I use this code to get a notion of what size squares to draw:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics); 
height = metrics.heightPixels; 
width = metrics.widthPixels;
```

....

```
landscape=width>height;
//use fudge factor for vertical display (account for title bar, etc.)
if (!landscape) 
    graphSize=(int) (0.9f*(float)height/2.0f);//reduce by 10%
if (landscape) 
    graphSize=width/2;
```

I use graphSize to set the size of the imageviews for output.

Recognizing that the width and height provided by the metrics only gives an approximation (for numerous reasons I do not wish to get into), I simply reduce the height by a fudge factor when sizing my squares. In landscape mode using width over 2 as the square size gives a good display which makes fairly good use of the available screen space. In portrait mode using height/2 works poorly: the second drawn square is diminished in size. So I reduce the height by 10% then divide by two to get the square size. This works but does not make good use of the available space. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear if you have other views along those two ImageViews in the LinearLayout. Without knowing the answer I wold say to make your own adapter.

Comment: I have no other views in the linear layout. Just the two squares.

Comment: Then a custom layout should work with no problems for what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be you want something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:weightSum="2">

 <ImageView
    .
    .
    .
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ImageView
    .
    .
    .
    android:layout_weight="1" />

 </LinearLayout>
```